# The best way to iterate SortedSet / SortedMap in Java backwards

Tags: java, collections

I need to iterate through SortedMap's entry set (which is a SortedSet) backwards. The code I'm writing is extremely performance-sensitive, as it's going to be called from many places thousands times per second, maybe more. Any advice on doing it the fastest way?

Comment: You mean, you need to iterate it forwards *and* backwards? Otherwise, just reverse your Comparator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Java 1.6 you can use [NavigableSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html).

Comment: NavigableSet descendingIterator()

Comment: Yep. Specifically, using NavigableSet.descendingIterator(). Or you can use NavigableSet.descendingSet() to get a view of the elements in reverse order which is backed by the existing set.

Comment: [According to Josh Bloch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw#t=1258), the author of both interfaces, ability to easily iterate in a reverse order is one of the main reasons why NavigableSet was introduced in Java 6.

Comment: Can you give an code example how to iterate a SortedSet with the help of the NavigableSet?

Comment: You replace the interfaces SortedMap and SortedSet by NavigableMap and NavigableSet, respectively.  With a SortedSet alone it is not possible, strictly speaking. (You might know that the underlying implementation supports NavigableMap and use a cast, but that would be a rather bad hack, and might break when the implementation changes.)

Answer (score 22):

use this before you fill your map :

```
SortedMap sortedMap = new TreeMap(java.util.Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Thanks! Much easier to add that than change the implementation to NavigableSet.

Answer (score 5):

A faster way to iterate a collection is to take an array copy of it. This can be iterated forward and backwards without creating an object or even a method call.  The downside is you need to update it as well as your collection whenever it changes.

In the following example, it takes an average of 1,208 ns to iterate over 1000 element either forward or backward.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.NavigableSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/*
Average time for iteration of 1000 elements was 1,208 ns
*/
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        doPerfTest(true);
        doPerfTest(false);
    }

    private static void doPerfTest(boolean warmup) {
        NavigableSet<MyData> set = new TreeSet<MyData>(new MyCompataror());
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            set.add(new MyData("text-" + random.nextLong(), random.nextInt()));
        }
        MyData[] myDatas = set.toArray(new MyData[set.size()]);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        final int runs = 500 * 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i+=2) {
            // forward iteration
            for (MyData md : myDatas) {

            }
            // reverse iteration
            for (int j = myDatas.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                MyData md = myDatas[j];
            }
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        if (!warmup)
            System.out.printf("Average time for iteration of 1000 elements was %,d ns", time / runs);
    }

    static class MyCompataror implements Comparator<MyData> {
        public int compare(MyData o1, MyData o2) {
            int cmp = o1.text.compareTo(o2.text);
            if (cmp != 0)
                return cmp;
            return o1.value > o2.value ? +1 :
                    o1.value < o2.value ? -1 : 0;
        }
    }

    static class MyData {
        String text;
        int value;

        MyData(String text, int value) {
            this.text = text;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now replace the main loop with and the average time becomes 20,493.

```
// forward iteration
for(Iterator<MyData> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    MyData md = it.next();
}
// reverse iteration
for(Iterator<MyData> it = set.descendingIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    MyData md = it.next();
}
```

Now lets compare this with taking a copy every time (which I have stated is not as optimal as taking a copy only when changed), the time drops to 15,134 ns!

So using NavigableSet could be the **slowest** of the three options discussed.

Comment: Array copy — every method call, more than 1000 times a second?! :)

Comment: Of course. Copying an array is about the fastest thing you can do in Java. Short benchmark: Copying a SortedSet with 1000 Objects and a custom Comparator that reverses the sort order takes about 0.8 ms. And that’s not even “just” a copy but also reverses the sort order. So, yes, it’s fast.

Comment: I said "you need to update it as well as your collection whenever it changes." not every method call. And you don't need to reverse sort an array if its already sorted.

Comment: Doing a toArray() of a sorted set with 1000 elements takes less than 14 micro-seconds (not that you should need to do this often)  I don't know how you get 0.8 ms. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a SortedMap such as a [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a custom [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that reverses the sorting order. If you need to iterate in both directions, then maybe it's feasible to keep *two* copies of the data structure in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Java 21 added the [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html#reversed()) method to `SortedMap`, which returns a reversed view of the map.

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.reversed().entrySet()) {
  // ...
}
```

or

```java
sortedMap.reversed().forEach((key, value) -> {
    // ...
});
```